# Privileges issue

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database (version 5.5), and I am trying to add a new user.
But I don't have the privileges to create it.If I try to show the list of all users:

```
select * from mysql.user;
```

It gives this error:

```
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user
```

It seems like I am not able to do anything.How to grant the privileges for a user without using the grant command?
There's a way? I also tried this:

```
CREATE USER 'ramy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

It says:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
```

I don't see any way to handle privileges, mysql show have a method to handle privileges for who have newly created a database.That's a vicious circle.

Comment: Do you have access to PHPMyAdmin or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to login as the 'root' account

See this if you don't know the root password

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html